# Is there a shortcut key to go to the next sibling folder in Windows Explorer (8.1)?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I'm going through a list of photo folders and keep on having to click on the next folder in the list. Is there a way to jump to the next sibling folder from the current folder with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: It is not a shortcut, but doesn't **Backspace+Down+Enter** do what you want?

Comment: in XP you did not have to hit enter, i miss that feature.

Comment: @Cornelius No, backspace goes to the previous folder location, like `Alt` + `Left Arrow`. I am in the file list when I need to go to the next sibling directory.

Comment: **Backspace** goes to parent, true, but it seems you missed what he said after that. **Down Arrow+Enter**. This combination takes probably the same amount of time as a real shortcut would do.

Comment: The screen has to flash before you enter the next button. Not the same at all. Whereas the need to look at N folders is very common.